# AutocompleteTextView hide suggestion

Tags: android, kotlin, autocompletetextview

In autocompletetextview, when I write text, the suggestions that do not contain this text disappear, how can I do that when I enter any text, all the suggestions will be still shown in android kotlin

I try

```
autocompleteTextView.doBeforeTextChanged { text, start, count, after ->  }
autocompleteTextView.doOnTextChanged { text, start, before, count ->  }
autocompleteTextView.doAfterTextChanged {  }
```

but it doesn't working